# zend -mysql using the value of one field value to another field name[edited]

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

Here is my table description:
CREATE TABLE my_table
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(9), `value` varchar(13))
;

INSERT INTO my_table
    (`id`, `name`, `value`)
VALUES
    (0, 'timezone', 'Europe/London'),
    (0, 'language', 'en'),
    (0, 'country', '45'),
    (0, 'something', 'x'),
    (1, 'timezone', 'Europe/Paris'),
    (1, 'language', 'fr'),
    (1, 'country', '46')
;

```
        id  name       value

        0   timezone    Europe/London
        0   language    en
        0   country     45
        0   something   x
        1   timezone    Europe/Paris
        1   language    fr
        1   country     46
```

My result should look

```
  ID     TIMEZONE       LANGUAGE      COUNTRY SOMETHING
  0      Europe/London  en            45      x
  1      Europe/Paris   fr            46      (null)
```

How can I execute this query in Zend Framework by using Zend_Db_Table or Zend_Db_Select? Thank you so much!

**[EDIT Query from comments added]**

```
SELECT CONCAT( 'SELECT table.id', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(' , t_', REPLACE(name, '', ''), '`.value AS `', REPLACE(name, '`', ''), '' ) SEPARATOR ''), ' 
FROM table` ', 
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(' LEFT JOIN table AS t_', REPLACE(name, '', ''), '` ON `table`.id = `t_', REPLACE(name, '`', ''), '.id AND t_', REPLACE(name, '', '``'), '.name = ', 
QUOTE(name) ) SEPARATOR ''), ' 
GROUP BY table.id' ) 
INTO @qry FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM table) t;

 PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
 EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: This is starting to feel like homework :)

Comment: prvious question not much clear. so ?

Comment: checked with sqlfiddle ,working only if we know the values of name unless ?

Comment: Do you know how to write such a query without Zend Framework?

Comment: What structure are you using? Are you doing this in the controller, in  a mapper or in a DbTable model? This info would make it easier to structure an answer.

Comment: SELECT CONCAT(
  'SELECT `table`.id', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('
     ,    `t_', REPLACE(name, '`', '``'), '`.value
         AS `', REPLACE(name, '`', '``'), '`'
   ) SEPARATOR ''),
 ' FROM `table` ', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('
     LEFT JOIN `table`   AS `t_', REPLACE(name, '`', '``'), '`
            ON `table`.id = `t_', REPLACE(name, '`', '``'), '`.id
           AND `t_', REPLACE(name, '`', '``'), '`.name = ', QUOTE(name)
   ) SEPARATOR ''),
 ' GROUP BY `table`.id'
) INTO @qry FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM `table`) t;

PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt; - but we can't use replace in zend,

Comment: Hi Rockey im using DbTable Model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a solution that uses [Zend_Db_Adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html) from a DbTable model:

```
/*accepts a string of SQL*/
public function getQuery($sql) {
    $query = $this->getAdapter->quoteInto($sql);
    $result = $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($query);
    /*if you want the result as an array instead of an object: $result->toArray()*/
    return $result;
}
```

I lack the SQL chops to parse your query and demonstrate the fluent interface. Good Luck.

Comment: Hi Rockey,Here is an clear example but can be done through mysql-http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e689/1

Comment: Sorry it still doesn't make any sense to me. Seems way over complicated. If I'm building the tables and queries I'm going to build a mapper class to map as many tables as is required to each Domain Entity/Object. This looks like you're trying to accomplish as much as possible in one query. I do simple and this isn't that.